# Adjusting a div based on screen sizing

Tags: html, css

I have these divs, however I can't seem to get them to display as a block. I somewhat have it, but when I zoom out on my screen, it goes back on that previous div..

I have `navigation-body` on `display: block;` & `icon-box-body` on `display: block;`

But when zoomed out, the `navigation-body` div goes back on the `icon-box-body` div line. Do you believe it has something to do with how I'm using the floats?

CSS:

```
.icon-box-body {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.icon-box {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #191919;
    border-color: #191919;
    color: #656565; 
    padding: 5px;
    width: 28px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 20%;
}

.icon-box.one{
    margin-left: 6px;
}

.icon-box.two{

}

.icon-box.three{
}

#navigation-body {
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="icon-box-body">
      <div class="icon-box one">one</div>
      <div class="icon-box two">two</div>
      <div class="icon-box three">three</div>
</div>

<div id="navigation-body">                      
        navigation                              
</div>
```

Here's an image:

[image]

but when zoomed in properly on default sizing, it looks perfect:

[image]

Comment: You could try adding a `clear: left;` to the `#navigation-body` style, as in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/troygizzi/m0j8dxmx/ However, it may not work on whatever mobile device you're using. Can you specify which platform/device you're testing on, and which ones you have to support?

Comment: It's a chrome browser, I'm just zooming in and out.

Comment: Three options. 1. Clear the float `#navigation-body { clear: left; }` 2. Self-clear the float `.icon-box-body:after { content: ' '; clear: both; display: block; height: 0; visibility: 0; }` 3. Use `display: inline-block` instead: `.icon-box-body div { display: inline-block }`